# How do you allow a large number of connections from a client in IIS?

Tags: iis

I am trying to do some performance testing on an ASP.NET application where I suspect most of the stress is currently on the database. I want to test entire round trips with the system to find the bottle necks, so I am starting a test application to hit my web service that starts up multiple threads to simulate multiple clients. However, IIS (7 on windows 7) seems to have a default limit per client of 5 concurrent connections.

I know that this limit is there for good reasons (like preventing DOS attacks), but is there a way to bump this up for my testing environment?

Comment: Is there any chance of testing it on a server version of Windows, e.g. Windows Server 2008 R2? You should test on the actual OS used for the server, not a desktop version of Windows. Also, if you think that the stress on the database is significant, you could instrument your calls to it to see if that really is the case, and you can monitor SQL Server performance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377023%28v=bts.10%29.aspx

Comment: A server OS will have the same connection limit to prevent DOS attacks (as mentioned above). While I suspect the main stress is on the database, I still need to prove (hence the test).

Comment: Connection from client(browser) to IIS or from IIS elsewhere?

Comment: @lehn0058 No, desktop versions of Windows have some limitations which the server versions do not: http://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/5997/windows-vista-7-iis-concurrent-connection-limits/

Comment: You are correct. I will attempt to do my tests against a server version of windows. Thanks!